# WeightingScale Issues Due to Applets

Tags: java, applet, classnotfoundexception, connectexception

In our application we load applet to read data from serial ports and USB ports of the machine. The applet code is working fine from past so many years but when we migrated to IE 11.0.44 version, the browser is hanging for 2 to 3 minutes while loading the applet. This is causing issues.

Below is the log file of the Java console. Could you please help us in resolving this issue.
Java Plug-in 10.80.2.15
Using JRE version 1.7.0_80-b15 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

### User home directory = C:\Users\aashish.pandey

c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache

### 0-5: set trace level to

```
cache: Initialize resource manager: com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl@138847d
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@40c4d5
security: Expected Main URL: https://cloud.shipconsole.com/ShipConsoleCloud/weighingscale.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for https://cloud.shipconsole.com/ShipConsoleCloud/weighingscale.jar
network: Cache entry not found [url: https://cloud.shipconsole.com/ShipConsoleCloud/weighingscale.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting https://cloud.shipconsole.com/ShipConsoleCloud/weighingscale.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jre7/lib/ext/sunec.jar, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jre7/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://cloud.shipconsole.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
basic: PluginMain.unregisterApplet: 1 from mananger sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2Manager@b66600
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1b206f
security: Expected Main URL: https://cloud.shipconsole.com/ShipConsoleCloud/weighingscale.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for https://cloud.shipconsole.com/ShipConsoleCloud/weighingscale.jar
basic: killed
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@40c4d5
network: Cache entry not found [url: https://cloud.shipconsole.com/ShipConsoleCloud/weighingscale.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting https://cloud.shipconsole.com/ShipConsoleCloud/weighingscale.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://cloud.shipconsole.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.retrieve(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFileInternal(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$1000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
network: Cache entry not found [url:https://cloud.shipconsole.com/ShipConsoleCloud/AascWeightScale.class, version: null]
network: Connecting https://cloud.shipconsole.com/ShipConsoleCloud/AascWeightScale.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://cloud.shipconsole.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Cache entry not found [url: https://cloud.shipconsole.com/ShipConsoleCloud/AascWeightScale/class.class, version: null]
network: Connecting https://cloud.shipconsole.com/ShipConsoleCloud/AascWeightScale/class.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://cloud.shipconsole.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AascWeightScale.class
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
basic: load: class AascWeightScale.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AascWeightScale.class
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Ignored exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AascWeightScale.class
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
security: Reset deny session certificate store
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1b206f
security: Reset deny session certificate store
```

Comment: It seems first this needs to be fixed: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AascWeightScale.class`

Comment: See also [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web) (for why there will likely be less interest in solving this problem).

Answer (score 0):

We are getting the classnotfound exception error when the applet is not loaded properly or it has some communication problem.

Thanks,
Ravi Teja